# How to Get temperature from weather underground day forcast

Tags: c#, asp.net, weather-api

I am using the weather underground api to get the 10 day weather forecast, everything is working fine I can get the low and high temperature for each of the returned day but in my application

I also  have to show the exact temperatures for the day ,

FOR example

i have to display something like this

```
                        **31c**       
                  hi:32c low:29c
                  WEATHER CONDITION : sunny
```

I can get all the values from the service ,  how can i retrieve the temperature that is right now  I think 31 refers to the temperature that is at the current moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with JSON passing from webservices? If not, it is a very worthwhile thing to take the time to learn.

The Weather Underground API site return JSON blobs from their services that contain the information you are looking for.

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

Specifically, they give the details for the forecast here:

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast10day

and to get the current temp among many other things here:

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/conditions